# Error when inserting contents from a Label into Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m making a leaderboard for a Facebook game, but I’m having difficulty showing the logged in player’s score inside a certain div.

My leaderboard is working perfectly, it successfully shows the “Rank”, “Name” and “Score” of each player (each of these elements are contained inside their own labels).

The problem I’m having is this:
In addition to having the logged in player’s score on the leaderboard, I also want to show it on it’s own in a separate div.

This is how I’m currently attempting to do this:

When the leaderboard is being generated, I assign each player’s “Rank” label a unique id. This id contains each user’s Facebook id, like this: `"ra_" + UsersFacebookId + "_nk"`. So an example of one of the ids would be: `"ra_123456789_nk"`.

Then I try to target the content of the logged in player’s “Rank” label, by storing their Facebook id as a variable (var userid), and then by attempting to use that variable to reference the contents of their individual Rank label like this:

```
var loggedInPlayersRank = document.getElementById("ra_"+userid+"_nk").innerHTML;
```

`console.log(userid);` is correct, it returns the user’s Facebook id.
`console.log("ra_"+userid+"_nk");` is also correct (it matches the id of the Rank label,  which has been generated in the leaderboard, that I’m trying to target).

The id of the div that I’m trying to fill in is `"playerRankCopy"`. This is my current attempt:

```
var targetId = "ra_"+userid+"_nk";
document.getElementById("playerRankCopy").innerHTML = document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML;
```

I have this code running right after the leaderboard is finished generating, but this isn’t working for me.

This is the HTML of the div I'm trying to copy the rank into:

```
<div id="playerRankCopy" class="friendranknumber">-</div>
```

And this is the HTML of the rank label which gets created dynamically when the leaderboard is generated:

```
<label id="ra_827366437284_nk">1st</label>
```

Can anyone help me work out why this code doesn’t fill in the div with the contents of the Rank div from the leaderboard?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you winding up with two id's in the same div tag?

Comment: Nevermind - it looks like you need quotes around playerRankCopy like: document.getElementById("playerRankCopy")

Comment: Hi @DanOrlovsky thanks for your reply, sorry that's my mistake, I do have quotes in my actual code, I forgot to include them in this question. It's still not working, I can't see what could be going wrong.

Comment: can you please include your HTML as well?

Comment: Hi @DanOrlovsky I've just added the relevant HTML to my question, could the cause be the fact that I'm trying to copy content from ``label`` to ``div``?

Comment: if you `console.log(loggedInPlayersRank);` what do you get? and for `console.log(document.getElementById("playerRankCopy").innerHTML);` and `console.log(document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML);` ?

Comment: have you tried using appendChild() var childDiv = document.getElementById("child-div");
document.getElementById("parent-div").appendChild(childDiv);

Comment: No, label to div is not the problem.  I'm guessing the problem is stemming from the code being executed before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Hi @DanOrlovsky , morels and kumar-utsav, thank you for your comments, it turns out the problem was being caused by not having the div and label in the correct order, I was actually inserting the empty div contents into the label by mistake, instead of the other way around, a really silly mistake! :) but thank you for your time and help, it's working now.